# SQL Server 2012 Filestream : An error occurred during the drop table operation on a FileTable object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server `filestream` feature in some databases to save profile pictures as files. I added new filegroup of type `filestream` and database file inside this filegroup. Also added a `filetable` and saved the files successfully and everything was fine.

For some reasons I have to remove the `filestream` from the database and the instance also.

I searched for the right steps to do that and found the following :

- drop all the filetables in the database using (Drop).
- Remove the Filesteam database files.
- Remove the Filestream filegroup.
- After that disable it at the instance level and the service.

The problem is when i started these steps (step one : Drop Table -FiletableName-) I got this error:

> An error occurred during the drop table operation on a FileTable object. (HRESULT = ‘0x80070490’)

I searched the internet for a solution and could not find one, does any one have a clue?.

Comment: See this   http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10406/completely-removing-filestream-features-from-a-sql-server-2008-database.aspx

Comment: Thanks but that blog is mentioning nothing about the error and is taking the happy path.

Comment: It starts with removing columns instead...

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but in FileTables you can't remove any column since they are auto-generated you can just drop the table. I think the blog is talking about SQL Server 2008 and FileTables Was first introduced in SQL Server 2012 [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the source of the problem to the above error.

I changed the [**Filestream Directory Name**] property to have a unique value and that removed the error and I was able to drop the table. That happened because I have restored another copy of the database with different database name in the same instance but did not change the [**Filestream Directory Name**] property.

You can find this property by right clicking the database, choosing **properties**, then choosing **Options** page, and under **Filestream** group of properties change [**Filestream Directory Name**] to have a unique value not used by other databases in the same instance.

[image]